# auth.authResponseChange - how to fire when status change

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am writing a script to check whether Facebook user is connected to our site, and this script is in the header file, so it will be called repeatedly when we calling another page, what I need is how to make this script fires only in status changed condition, may I know how to do that? the script I am using is as below:-

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  //Attaches an handler to an event
});
```

'auth.authResponseChange' - fired when the authResponse changes

I think it is not working correctly, this command still fires when we refresh the page even the user status is remaining the same condition. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? thanks all and have a nice dream.

Answer (score 2):

The FB object (the one on which you call FB.login(), FB.api() etc.) does not live between page loads. On each page load it is recreated, and at some point during each page load it receives an authResponse for the first time. From the POV of the FB object this is a change from unknown to known, so it fires the change event.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Does it ever fire at any other time? For example, what would trigger it going from known back to unknown? Logging out in a separate tab doesn't seem to fire anything